# AWS Cognito SNS not sending verification of user phone number sms message to Sprint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-sns

I'm trying to send sms confirmation messages with Amazon SNS to the phones of users who sign up for an account using cognito and verify their phone numbers. My cognito user pool is located at us-east-2 and I recently got my spend limit increased to $50 for both us-east-1 and us-east-2. I tested sending sms messages through the sns console to my phone and that works perfectly. However, I don't get the sms messages when trying to verify users on cognito. When checking the sns console, it looks like the only successful messages that are being sent to my phone were my manual sent messages from the console and everything else has failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have found that the error comes for my specific phone number as a sprint carrier and get the following log failed response:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "messageId": "5dab56f3-2dd3-5a6d-b96e-0e96904d334b",
        "timestamp": "2020-12-29 23:27:26.712"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "phoneCarrier": "SPRINT Spectrum L.P.",
        "mnc": 880,
        "numberOfMessageParts": 1,
        "destination": "+1******3252",
        "priceInUSD": 0.00645,
        "smsType": "Transactional",
        "mcc": 311,
        "providerResponse": "Blocked as spam by phone carrier",
        "dwellTimeMs": 202,
        "dwellTimeMsUntilDeviceAck": 1254
    },
    "status": "FAILURE"
}
```

However, I tested with an AT&T phone and TMobile phone and they get the messages delivered successfully with the following log response:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "messageId": "3106a00c-40de-53ce-9f40-f869fc025013",
        "timestamp": "2020-12-29 23:24:12.183"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "phoneCarrier": "T-mobile USA Inc.",
        "mnc": 800,
        "numberOfMessageParts": 1,
        "destination": "+1******1131",
        "priceInUSD": 0.00645,
        "smsType": "Transactional",
        "mcc": 310,
        "providerResponse": "Message has been accepted by phone",
        "dwellTimeMs": 238,
        "dwellTimeMsUntilDeviceAck": 601251
    },
    "status": "SUCCESS"
}
```

This error is really weird to me as there should be no reason why SPRINT blocks my phone from getting sms messages from aws sns on cognito only but other phone services allow getting messages. I also still am able to get messages from the SNS console but only cognito fails to send with the carrier blocking it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to receive SNS SMS from AT&T and T-Mobile phone carrier, I would strongly suggest that you contact [AWS Premium Support](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aws-phone-support/) to help you identify why SMS sent to **SPRINT Spectrum L.P.** are not being delivered.